# getting an RunTime Error (mat1 and mat2....) when trying to use a trained FNN model in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

In my model there are 5 float inputs and one output (LWS= 1\0).
while training the model there was no problem, but when I tried to load the model and check it on new data I got the "mat1 and mat2..." error.
i used this website to build my model(https://curiousily.com/posts/build-your-first-neural-network-with-pytorch/).

[the dataset (LWS is the output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlg4Y.png)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd
import collections #to test itterabillity
import numpy as np
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ofer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\DEW_Data_NNN.csv')
#train = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ofer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\DEW_Data_NN_train.xlsx')
#test = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ofer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\DEW_Data_NN_test.csv')


#df.drop(labels='Time',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.drop(labels='Rad',axis=1,inplace=True)
df.drop(labels='Baro',axis=1,inplace=True)
input_col_names = df.columns

RANDOM_SEED = 42
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

#dividing the df to test and train df's
# X = inputs; Y = output
X = df[input_col_names[:(len(a)-1)]]
y = df[['LWS']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

#converting df's to tensors
X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.to_numpy()).float()
y_train = torch.squeeze (torch.from_numpy(y_train.to_numpy()).float())
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test.to_numpy()).float()
y_test = torch.squeeze (torch.from_numpy(y_test.to_numpy()).float())

#BUilding a neural network

class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_features):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_features, 5)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 3)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)
  def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    return torch.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))

net = Net(X_train.shape[1])

#training - a loss function, closer to 0 the better
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
#optimization - to reduce the loss function
#lr=learning rate
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

#converting every value below 0.5 to 0. Otherwise, we set it to 1. Finally, we calculate the percentage of correct values
def calculate_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  predicted = y_pred.ge(.5).view(-1)
  return (y_true == predicted).sum().float() / len(y_true)

def round_tensor(t, decimal_places=3):
  return round(t.item(), decimal_places)
for epoch in range(2000):
    y_pred = net(X_train)
    y_pred = torch.squeeze(y_pred)
    train_loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
      train_acc = calculate_accuracy(y_train, y_pred)
      y_test_pred = net(X_test)
      y_test_pred = torch.squeeze(y_test_pred)
      test_loss = criterion(y_test_pred, y_test)
      test_acc = calculate_accuracy(y_test, y_test_pred)
      print(
f'''epoch {epoch}
Train set - loss: {round_tensor(train_loss)}, accuracy: {round_tensor(train_acc)}
Test  set - loss: {round_tensor(test_loss)}, accuracy: {round_tensor(test_acc)}
''')
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    train_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

model_path = 'model.pth'
torch.save(net, model_path)

classes = ['No dew', 'dew']
y_pred = net(X_test)
y_pred = y_pred.ge(.5).view(-1).cpu()
y_test = y_test.cpu()
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=classes))

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, index=classes, columns=classes)
hmap = sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt="d")
hmap.yaxis.set_ticklabels(hmap.yaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=0, ha='right')
hmap.xaxis.set_ticklabels(hmap.xaxis.get_ticklabels(), rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label');

def will_it_dew(Time, Wind_Speed, Air_Temp, RH):
  t = torch.as_tensor([Time, Wind_Speed, Air_Temp, RH]) \
      .float() \
      .to(device)
  output = net(t)
  return output.ge(0.5).item()

#will_it_dew(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: thank you, but still, I get this error after I train the model without saving and loading it. (and also when i save and load in the right way)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way of saving the model...and often throws error when you use it from different folder / different path

Recommended approach for saving a model
There are two main approaches for serializing and restoring a model.

The first (recommended) saves and loads only the model parameters:

```
torch.save(the_model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

Then later:

```
the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
the_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

The second saves and loads the entire model:
This is what you have done

```
torch.save(the_model, PATH)
```

Then later:

```
the_model = torch.load(PATH)
```

However in this case, the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used, so it can break in various ways when used in other projects, or after some serious refactors.